# Use HTML/CSS/Javascript to open links in new pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that is represented in multiple pages across my site. I don't want to set each one specifically to open in a new window, rather I want all links in that specific div to open in a new window. How can I do this using HTML/ CSS/ javascript?

Thanks

Comment: @Neal, normally I would agree with you, but the code isn't going to tell us anything more than what golf_nut described verbally. It was a well written question.

Answer (score 2):

here's how you could do that with jQuery

if you have something like `<div class="myLinks">...</div>`

```
$('.myLinks a').attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: This would work, but word of caution. If someone clicks on a link before the DOM has completed loading (slower connection) it will not open in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess there are two reasonable ways to open the *href* from an *anchor* in a new window.

- Edit the `node` and set its `target` to `_blank` (`<a href="foo" target="_blank"></a>`)
- Use Javascript to catch the *click event*, prevent the default behavior and call `window.open()`

  ```
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv a');
  [].forEach.call(anchors, function(anchor) { 
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
          window.open(e.target.href, 'mywindow', '_blank');

          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
      }, false);
  });
  ```

That example code is vanilla Javascript and it'll only work in a W3C compliant browser (!= IE).
If you can afford to you use a JS framework live is going to be easier since all of those will abstract browser differences for you.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Love that you wrote Javascript first before recommending a framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a div and link like this in some pages:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="Link Url">Link Text</a>
    <!--some other elements-->
</div>
```

you need to create a js file  like bellow and add it to end of all of your pages :

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if (div) {
    for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        if (div.childNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a")
            div.childNodes[i].target = "_blank";
    }
}
```

And its all things you need to do !
this code is fast enough and even does not need JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and jQuery.

First of all I suggest that DIV have id `outgoing`.

```
<div id='outgoing'>
    <a href='http://google.com'>Go to Google</a><br>
    <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Look at SO!</a>
</div>
```

Now we can use simple JavaScript to dynamiclaly add `target='blank'` into these links:

```
$(function() {
    $('#outgoing a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

[You can check example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FYQvW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use jQuery to iterate through all links within a specified div, then set the target to "_blank".